# How can i what line javascript trigger a post request?

Tags: javascript

Now I have a html page . It will send a post request to an url in loading. But I don't known which one DOM element trigger the event. What can I do ? I use chrome.

Comment: Use the "XHR breakpoint" feature if it's a request being made by JavaScript, or set a DOM Event Breakpoint on `unload` if it's something like a `<form>` being submitted or `<meta refresh>`.

Comment: @Dai, XHR breakpoint can help if you're making Ajax request but OP is asking about a post request which can be something like this `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`.

Comment: @derloopkat That's something that would be caught by the DOM `unload` event breakpoint which I mentioned.